# My function for generating random numbers isn't going past 500000

Tags: arrays, c, random, data-structures, numbers

I'll get right into my problem. So basically what I want to do is to generate an array of random numbers of different amounts. So one with 10,000, 50,000, 100,000, 500,000, 600,000, etc. Then I would sort them using quicksort and print the sorted array to the screen. Additionally, the time taken for it to run would be recorded and printed as well. The only part I'm having problems with however is generating the array. For some reason generating past 500,000 random numbers does not work and returns this:

---

Process exited after 2.112 seconds with return value 3221225725

Press any key to continue . . .
([1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m83el.png)

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void randNums(int array[], int range) {
    int i, num;
    for (i = 0; i < range; i++) {
        num = rand() % range;
        array[i] = num;
    }
}

//prints elements of given array
void display(int array[], int size) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("#%d. %d\n", i, array[i]);
    }
}

//displays time taken for sorting algorithm to run
void timeTaken(char sortingAlgo[], int size, clock_t start, clock_t end) {
    double seconds = end - start;
    double milliseconds = seconds / 1000;
    printf("Time taken for %s Sort to sort %d numbers was %f milliseconds or %f seconds",
           sortingAlgo, size, milliseconds, seconds);       
}
 
//quick sort
void quickSort(int array[], int first, int last) {
    int i, j, pivot, temp;
    if (first < last) {
        pivot = first;
        i = first;
        j = last;
        while (i < j) {
            while (array[i] <= array[pivot] && i < last)
                i++;
            while (array[j] > array[pivot])
                j--;
            if (i < j) {
                temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[j];
                array[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        temp = array[pivot];
        array[pivot] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
        quickSort(array, first, j - 1);
        quickSort(array, j + 1, last);
    }
}

int main() { 
    int size = 600000;
    int myArray[size];
    time_t end, start;
    int first, last;

    randNums(myArray, size);    
    first = myArray[0];
    last = sizeof(myArray) / sizeof(myArray[0]);
    
    time(&start);
    quickSort(myArray, first, last);
    time(&end); 
    display(myArray, size);
    timeTaken("Quick", size, start, end);

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: What is your `RAND_MAX`?

Comment: Your stack size is limited, large arrays cause problems. Use `calloc()` or `malloc()` if you're using anything non-trivial in size.

Comment: Oh wow okay, I was thinking of that but I didn't wanna overcomplicate things and I'm really not that good with memory allocation. Thank you!
Also, I'm not sure about the RAND_MAX thing.

Comment: I just mention `RAND_MAX` because on some systems it's really puny, 32767 or less, which means for large arrays you'll have lots of duplicated values. Always be aware of stack limitations. ~1000 items is fine, but beyond that you start to run into the danger zone. Remember the stack is for the *whole* program so you need to avoid putting heavy things in it.

Comment: OHHHH okay gotcha. Thanks. Sorry, I'm still a bit new to C and its intricacies. 
I looked up a bit more on malloc() and gave it a try. I'm pleased to say that it worked with generating the number of integers I needed just fine. However, now my quicksort function does not work with it, unlike before.

Comment: I'll have to look a bit more into that if I can find resources on it particularly. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: "Does not work" isn't a technical description of the problem, and that sort of thing is really important here. We can only help if you can explain what happened: Tell us precisely what errors you got, or what the output was and how that was unexpected or incorrect.

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry, I'm kinda young and new to all of this. I had changed the main part of the code by declaring the array like this `int *myArray;` and allocating the memory of it like this `myArray = (int *)malloc(size * sizeof(int));`. 
I also changed the "first" and "last" variable to this 
`first = myArray[0];`
`last = myArray[size-1];`
Because I realized that what I was using to get the last element in the array was incorrect.

Comment: As for why I said it didn't work, well, it worked in the sense I was able to generate the numbers past 500,000 but, the numbers were not being sorted when I passed it into the quicksort function. It just kept returning the same random, unsorted numbers when I printed it using the display function. Sorry if I was unclear, it had solved the initial problem that I had posted and I didn't want to bother anyone else any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of little bugs in this code that aren't too difficult to resolve. I'll try and break it down here in this refactoring and cleanup:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void randNums(int* array, int range) {
  // Declare iterator variables like `i` within the scope of the iterator.
  for (int i = 0; i < range; i++) {
    // No need for a single-use variable here, just assign directly.
    array[i] = rand () % range;
  }
}

void display(int* array, int size) {
  // for is not a function, it's a control flow mechanism, so
  // it is expressed as `for (...)` with a space. `for()` implies
  // it is a function, which it isn't.
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("#%d. %d\n", i, array[i]);
  }
}

void timeTaken(char* sortingAlgo, int size, clock_t start, clock_t end) {
  // Time calculation here needs to account for the fact that clock_t
  // does not use seconds as units, it must be converted
  // https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock_t

  printf(
    "Time taken for %s Sort to sort %d numbers was %.6f seconds",
    sortingAlgo,
    size,
    ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC
  );
}

void quickSort(int* array, int first, int last) {
   // Establish a guard condition. Rest of the function is no longer
   // nested in a control flow structure, so it simplifies the code.
   if (first >= last) {
     return;
   }

  int pivot = first;
  int i = first;
  int j = last;

  // Use `while (...)` as it's also a control flow structure.
  while (i < j) {
    // Adding space around operators improves clarity considerably. Unspaced
    // elements like `a->b()` are supposed to stand out and not be confused
    // with visually similar `a>>b()` which does something very different.
    while (array[i] <= array[pivot] && i < last) {
      i++;
    }

    // Use surrounding braces on all blocks, even single-line ones, as this
    // can avoid a whole class of errors caused by flawed assumptions.
    // while (...) { ... }
    while (array[j] > array[pivot]) {
      j--;
    }

    if (i < j) {
      int temp = array[i];
      array[i] = array[j];
      array[j] = temp;
    }
  }

  int temp = array[pivot];
  array[pivot] = array[j];
  array[j] = temp;

  quickSort(array, first, j - 1);
  quickSort(array, j + 1, last);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  int size = 600000;

  // If an argument was given...
  if (argc > 1) {
    // ...use that as the size parameter instead.
    size = atol(argv[1]);
  }

   // Allocate an array of sufficient size
  int* numbers = calloc(size, sizeof(int));

  randNums(numbers, size);

  // time_t has at best second-level precision, it's very inaccurate.
  // Use clock_t which gives far more fidelity.
  clock_t start = clock();

  // This function takes *offsets*, not values.
  quickSort(numbers, 0, size - 1);

  clock_t end = clock();

  display(numbers, size);

  timeTaken("Quick", size, start, end);

  free(numbers);

  return 0;
}
```

The number one bug here was calling `quickSort()` incorrectly:

```c
// Represents first *value* in the array
first = myArray[0]; // Should be: 0

// Rough calculation of the size of the array, but this is off by one
last = sizeof(myArray)/sizeof(myArray[0]); // Should be: size - 1
    
quickSort(myArray, first, last);
```

Comment: WOW. Thank you so very much. This really solves my initial problem and other problems I had thereafter and includes a lot of stuff I really didn't know about. Thanks for your help, time, and insight, I will put it to good use by learning and practicing more.